# Android App Exits when Going into Background

Tags: android, background, exit, multitasking, ondestroy

Ever since I added a new Class to my Android app (specifically, a sqlite helper class) may app wants to relaunch after I press the home button.  Before adding the class, the app would multitask as expected.

I am stumped. It seems onDestroy is called every time the app goes into the background.

Any tips or thoughts as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true" in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Please refer to [Android activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more info when/how your activity could be destroyed. Basically, as soon as your app goes into background, your activity can be killed at any moment.

If you want to continue execution, you need to create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that represents a long-running components in Android architecture.

Comment: It turned out I had **android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"** in the manifest file. IDK how it got there, but that's just part of the fun I guess. Thanks for the answer.